# Android alert notification using alarm manager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

```
   bookAppoinmentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
              setAlarm(String time, String strDate);
            }
        });  
  public void setAlarm(String time, String strDate){
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
        String hour=formateDateFromstring("HH:mm","HH",time);
        String min=formateDateFromstring("HH:mm","mm",time);
        String date=formateDateFromstring("yyyy-MM-dd","dd",strDate);
        String month=formateDateFromstring("yyyy-MM-dd","MM",strDate);
        String year=formateDateFromstring("yyyy-MM-dd","yyyy",strDate);

        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(date));  //1-31
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(month));  //first month is 0!!! January is zero!!!
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(year));//year...
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hour));  //HOUR
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(min));       //MIN

        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
    }
```

Here i am using alarm manager to send notification for the selected time and date.I tried sample project with the same code its working after that i integrated with my project its not working.

//Here is my code for receiver

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context mcontext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.mcontext = context;

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logob_icon_prestigesalon)
                .setContentTitle("ABC")
                .setContentText("time to go")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());


    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: i am not receiving notification

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, I have found how to sent notifications using Alarm Manager in Kotlin. I have added the following stuff. In here, I have schedule the alarm for every minutes, so that it will trigger in every minutes(For my case, checking a time from Realm Database, and fire notification on that particular time). This notification will trigger even when your app is closed( removed from recent task). But I don't know whether this is the correct way. I have tested in Android R(11) and also on emulator, in both case it works fines.

create a the following  function and call  from your activity

```
 private fun scheduleAlarm() {
    val alarmIntent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    alarmIntent.putExtra("data", "Pass your message")
    val pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val afterOneMinutes = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1 * 1 * 1000

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, afterTwoMinutes, 1000 * 1, pendingIntent
    ) else alarmManager.setExact(
        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        afterOneMinutes , pendingIntent
    )

}
```

You can set the repeating time in here,
`val afterOneMinutes = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1 * 1 * 1000`
Here I'm repeating in every one minutes.

The main logic comes in Broadcast Receiver class(My case)

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Alarm received")

    if("Your Condition")
    {
        sendNotification(context, intent.getStringExtra("data"))
    }

}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun sendNotification(mcontext: Context, messageBody: String?)
{
    val intent = Intent(mcontext, YourActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        mcontext, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    val notificationManager =
        mcontext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val defaultSoundUri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
            mcontext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id),
            "Rewards Notifications",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.description = "Channel description"
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
        notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 500, 200, 500)
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }
    val notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(
        mcontext,
        mcontext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
    )
        .setContentTitle(mcontext.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

}

In here, I have set a condition in onReceive() method. If condition is true, it fires the notification. You can also use firebase real-time database changes, time changes, database changes, or any other condtions, whatever you want.

Don't forget to register receiver in manifest

I hope it will useful for some peoples and happy coding..............